# Bus connectivity between Jasidih and Munger

Tags: public-transport, india, buses

I will exactly be traveling between **Rikhiapeeth** ashram to **Bihar School of Yoga**. I believe there no direct connectivity and hence looking for nearest cities.
I would like to know if there is any bus connectivity between **Jasidih, Jharkhand** and **Munger, Bihar**. I searched online but seems no website provides tickets between the two. So a local may be able to tell me if the two cities are connected by bus or other road mean, and if yes how frequent?

If direct buses are not available, is there any connectivity between nearby cities, for reference I am mentioning a few local cities:

**Jasidih**: Deoghar

**Munger**: Jamalpur, Bariarpur

I know there runs train between **Deoghar** and **Jamalpur Jn**, but the timings do not suit me.

Comment: According to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Jasidih/Munger) there is no alternative to the train. Unless you have some suspicion that there might be a bus nonetheless, I assume that is really the case. Posting as comment instead of answer to leave open this Q to others who might know better.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find you a bus, but there are other options, according to [rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Jasidih/Munger):

- Train, US$24-33 - will take just under 4 hours
- Taxi - around 2 hours, US$75-95 (having just been in India, this seems outrageous, I'm sure on the ground you could find it for a fraction of the price
- Drive - ah, perhaps this is the regular driver option,  for US$15-23.

On the ground I'd ask a local if there might be a bus or shared taxi, but at the very least, there are some direct options (as above).

Answer (score 0):

try this site -

http://www.cleartrip.com/tourism/routes/dd/munger-to-deoghar-route.html

the distance between two places is 140 km. you should be able to hire a car (with driver) and should not cost you more than 7-8 Rs per km.

Comment: Is this your site?

Comment: No. Its a travel portal